# Какую тему выбрать для димплома по разработке информационных систем?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу написать информационную систему для диплома ,но пока не определился какую тему выбрать.Думал что то в сфере общепита,ресторан,кафэ.Но там слишком много сущностей ,официант для него нужна мобилка,и т .д
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какую тему выбрать интересную для диплома,чтобы была не очень сложная.Собирабсь писпть на c# изпользуя Net Core ,MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти в сторону CRM, товары и заказы например, или кадрами и персоналом компании.

---

Идея по CRM в сфере продаж:

1. Профили клиентов - управление данными о покупателе(телефон, соцсети) и различной информацией с пометками
2. Продажи - управление статусами заказов и ведение различных документаций
3. Товары - управление категориями товаров, редактирование товаров, управление метками и различными параметрами товаров
4. Задачи и доставки - аналогично продажам, добавляем уведомления и тд.
5. Документооборот - подведение различных сверок, генерация отчётных документов и тд.
6. Анализ данных - различные графики и статистики по товарам и категориям
7. Интеграция (тот же живосайт) или реализация собственного чата с клиентом - поддержка пользователей, горячие сообщения
8. Интеграция с метриками типо яндекса или гугла - изучение конверсии переходов и кликов по кнопкам

Comment: Да я хочу сделать CRM только вот какую тематику выбрать?Можете накидать варианты для CRM?

Comment: И если вы делали CRM можете поделиться опытом ,что обязательно должно быть в CRM?

Comment: Я знаю что должен быть клиент и продавец .Менеджер или продавец добавляет товары в чек  и выбирает клиента ,после чего клиент оплачивает и данные добавляются в таблицу продаж

Comment: @ilya правильно ли я понимаю, в дипломной работе должно быть взаимодействие клиента и продавца? Или это может быть внутренний продукт?

Comment: В дипломе должна быть  реализована Информационная система ,я хочу CRM это взаимодействие клиента и продавца или менеджера

Comment: @ilya CRM это очень обобщённое понятие, у неё много разных ответвлений, в том числе и с взаимодействиями с конечными пользователями, сейчас накидаю идею а обновление)

Comment: 3,6 пункт я собираюсь реализовывать CRM система в ней товары и работа с ними а также работа с клиентами и продажами

Comment: @ilya все пункты это реализация одной небольшой полноценной црм)

Comment: Да вы что ! Я просто сильно видимо не разбираюсь в CRM ,но хочу разобраться .

Answer (score 1):

Автоматизация учета проходящих через КПП с помощью ардуинки: читаешь RFID метку и из UID который ты считал с метки вытаскиваешь какого-нибудь человека из бд, а затем выводишь в UI его персональные данные (фото, ФИО итд). Реализация очень простая т.к по ардуинке всё в интернете уже готово, а выглядит зрелищно

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но я думаю мне ближе копать в сторону CRM .Не могли бы посоветовать тематику для CRM ? Я делал небольшие CRM но это была продажа продуктов  клиентам.Мне нужно чтобы тема плюшевой не была ,а что то по серьезщнее

Comment: CRM контроля качества пива в барах какой-нибудь сети на основе отзывов постоянных посетителей

Comment: Я с пивом не шарю)можно что нибудь из сферы продуктов питания или общепита?

Comment: У меня планируется мобилка заказ ,а CRM продажа клиентам и учет продукции

Comment: @ilya ну тогда доставка еды типа деливери или яндекс яды или любой другой) В CRM можно будет добавлять рестораны и их блюда, а с мобилки просматривать добавленные + делать заказы

Comment: Спасибо! Можно пообщаться с вами в телеграмм ,вк или вотсап? Мне как раз не хватает общения с профи разработчиками ,хотел бы спросить про CRM мой телеграмм @ilya2003_21. Буду рад знакомству и общению